# CSS Grid Auto Columns, make one column larger

Tags: css-grid

I've created a grid layout using grid auto columns. Requirements I'm looking for are as follows:

- Columns fill the width of the grid completely.
- By default grid divides columns equally.
- Ability to control order of columns.
- Ability to control width of specific column and remaining columns take up space equally.

The grid container css is:

```
.gridLayout {
    grid-auto-columns: minmax(0, 1fr);
    grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

The html markup is as follows:

```
<div class="gridLayout">
    
   <div class="gridSection textHolder">
      <p>Text</p>
   </div><!--/.gridSection-->

   <div class="gridSection imageOneHolder">
      <img />
   </div><!--/.gridSection-->

   <div class="gridSection imageTwoHolder">
      <img />
   </div><!--/.gridSection-->

</div><!--/.gridLayout-->
```

The only requirement I cannot get to work is to control the width of a specific column.

For example I cannot get the 'textHolder' column to be 66% of the width of the grid? If I apply a width to it it affects the content within that grid area.

Using grid-template-areas isn't really an option due to the potential permutations of order and width.

Am I missing something obvious, or should I just use flex instead?

Comment: The gridLayout element is set to display: grid elsewhere in the css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grid` is built around fractions (1) or template-areas (2).
Setting a specific width by CSS on a column only (without using `grid-template-columns` on the container) is not possible AFAIK.

For self-sizing columns, indeed `flex` is more suited IMHO.

But what you can do from the column level is increase the fraction it is going to take:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: minmax(0, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
.grid > .col-2 {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}

/* debug */
.grid > * {
  border: 1px dashed darkmagenta;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-2">
    double size
  </div>
  <div>
    normal size
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    double size
  </div>
</div>

<hr>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-2">
    2/3
  </div>
  <div>
    1/3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas, I'll revert back to flex - I just find it's calculations can be a few pixels off which misaligns vertical column gaps.